# How to allow the user to type only under certain conditions in pygame?

Tags: python, text, pygame, drawing

When you click the textbox I want the user to be able to type letters by setting self.active to True. When you click off the text box I want the player to lose that ability by setting self.active to False. However when I click the text box, self.active becomes true for a split second before becoming False again. How do I fix this?

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))

name_font = font.Font(None, 32)
name_text = ''


class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.active = False
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        self.rect_width = max(140, 10 + self.text_surface.get_width())
        self.input_rect = Rect(x, y, self.rect_width, 32)
        draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), self.input_rect, 0)
        draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.input_rect, 2)
        self.input_rect.w = self.text_surface.get_width() + 10
        screen.blit(self.text_surface, (self.input_rect.x + 5, self.input_rect.y + 5))

    def naming(self):
        global rect_1
        global name_text

        if events.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.input_rect.x + 150 >= mx >= self.input_rect.x - 10:
                if self.input_rect.y + 40 >= my >= self.input_rect.y - 10:
                    self.active = True
            if not self.input_rect.x + 150 >= mx >= self.input_rect.x - 10:
                if not self.input_rect.y + 40 >= my >= self.input_rect.y - 10:
                    self.active = False

        if self.active:
            if events.type == KEYDOWN:
                if keys[K_BACKSPACE]:
                    name_text = name_text[:-1]
                    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                    rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)
                else:
                    name_text += events.unicode


while True:
    rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)
    mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
    for events in event.get():
        keys = key.get_pressed()
        rect_1.naming()
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()

    display.update()
    time.delay(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the instance of `Rectangle` before the application loop, but you have to pass the list of events to the method `naming` and to handle all the relevant events in the method.
Add a `draw` method to the class and draw the object in every frame:

```py
class Rectangle:
    # [...]

    def naming(self, events):
        # [...]

        for event in evetnts:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                # [...]

        
            if e.type == # [...]

    def draw(self, screen):
        # [...]
```

```py
rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)

run = True
while run :
    
    events = event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type == QUIT:
            run = False
    
    rect_1.naming(events)

    # [...]

    rect_1.draw(screen)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))

name_font = font.Font(None, 32)
name_text = ''


class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.active = False
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        self.rect_width = max(140, 10 + self.text_surface.get_width())
        self.input_rect = Rect(x, y, self.rect_width, 32)
        draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), self.input_rect, 0)
        draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.input_rect, 2)
        self.input_rect.w = self.text_surface.get_width() + 10
        screen.blit(self.text_surface, (self.input_rect.x + 5, self.input_rect.y + 5))

    def naming(self, events):
        global rect_1
        global name_text

        for e in events:
            if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mx, my = e.pos
                if self.input_rect.x + 150 >= mx >= self.input_rect.x - 10:
                    if self.input_rect.y + 40 >= my >= self.input_rect.y - 10:
                        self.active = True
                if not self.input_rect.x + 150 >= mx >= self.input_rect.x - 10:
                    if not self.input_rect.y + 40 >= my >= self.input_rect.y - 10:
                        self.active = False

            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if self.active:
                    if e.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                        name_text = name_text[:-1]
                    else:
                        name_text += e.unicode
                    self.text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    
    def draw(self, screen):
        draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), self.input_rect, 0)
        draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.input_rect, 2)
        self.input_rect.w = self.text_surface.get_width() + 10
        screen.blit(self.text_surface, (self.input_rect.x + 5, self.input_rect.y + 5))


rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)

run = True
while run :
    
    events = event.get()
    for e in events:
        if e.type == QUIT:
            run = False
    
    rect_1.naming(events)

    screen.fill(0)
    rect_1.draw(screen)  
    display.update()
    time.delay(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to take line 47 "rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)" out of the while loop because you keep recreating the box and it instantiates a new box with an active value equal to false.

Comment: @Python2019 is mistaken mx and my are updated and compared when the mouse is clicked he doesn't get them with global but he still uses them. I have run the code the box actives when click and deactivates when another click outside of it happens when you change what I said before.

Answer (score 0):

> You are getting the mouse position but not doing anything with it like comparing it to the location of the box.  if you start with self.active = True you can type in the box regardless of where the cursor is.